# Bash sanitize_file_name function

Tags: php, wordpress, bash, sanitization

I'm attempting to find a way to sanitize/filter file names in a Bash script the exact same way as the `sanitize_file_name` function from WordPress works. It has to take a filename string and spit out a clean version that is identical to that function.

[You can see the function here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/formatting.php#L1762).

> GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
>   Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-57-generic x86_64)
>   This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

**Example input file names**
These can be and often are practically anything you can make a filename on any operating system, especially Mac and Windows.

```
This File + Name.mov  
Some, Other - File & Name.mov  
ANOTHER FILE 2 NAME vs2_.m4v  
some & file-name Alpha.m4v  
Some Strange & File ++ Name__.mp4  
This is a - Weird -@ Filename!.mp4
```

**Example output file names**
These are how the WordPress `sanitize_file_name` function makes the examples above.

```
This-File-Name.mov  
Some-Other-File-Name.mov  
ANOTHER-FILE-2-NAME-vs2_.m4v  
some-file-name-Alpha.m4v  
Some-Strange-File-Name__.mp4  
This-is-a-Weird-@-Filename.mp4
```

It doesn't just have to solve these cases, it has perform the same functions that the `sanitize_file_name` function does or it will produce duplicate files and they won't be updated on the site.

Some thoughts I've had are maybe I can somehow use that function itself but this video encoding server doesn't have PHP on it since it's quite a tiny server and normally just encodes videos and uploads them. It doesn't have much memory, CPU power or disk space, it's a DigitalOcean 512MB RAM server. Maybe I can somehow create a remote PHP script on the web server to handle it through HTTP but again I'm not entirely sure how to do that either through Bash.

It's too complicated for my limited Bash skills so I'm wondering if anyone can help or knows where a script is that does this already. I couldn't find one. All I could find are scripts that change spaces or special characters into underscores or dashes. But this isn't all the `sanitize_file_name` function does.

In case you are curious, the filenames have to be compatible with this WordPress function because of the way this website is setup to handle videos. It allows people to upload videos through WordPress that are then sent to a separate video server for encoding and then sent to Amazon S3 and CloudFront for serving on the site. However it also allows adding videos through Dropbox using the External Media plugin (which actually is duplicating the video upload with the Dropbox sync now but that's another minor issue). This video server is also syncing to a Dropbox account and whitelisting the folders in it and has this Bash script watching a VideoServer Dropbox folder using `inotifywait` which copies videos from it to another folder temporarily where the video encoder encodes them. This way when they update the videos in their Dropbox it will automatically re-encode and update the video shown on the site. They could just upload the files through WordPress but they don't seem to want to or don't know how to do that for some reason.

Comment: Show us some sample file-names and the `bash` version you are using by `bash --version` and how you would like to _sanitize_ it

Comment: Please remove the comment above and update it as part of the question. Provide a clear and verifiable input example and an expected output. Your current information is not helping unfortunately

Comment: Sorry, I'm a noob. I tried to add more details and whatnot. It wouldn't let me save it unless I marked the filenames as code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Perl installed, try with:

```
#!/bin/bash

function sanitize_file_name {
    echo -n $1 | perl -pe 's/[\?\[\]\/\\=<>:;,''"&\$#*()|~`!{}%+]//g;' -pe 's/[\r\n\t -]+/-/g;'
}

filename="Wh00t? it's a -- re@lly-weird {file&name} (with + Plus and__1% #of# [\$qRots\$!]).mov"

cleaned=$(sanitize_file_name "$filename")

echo original : "$filename"
echo sanitised: "$cleaned"
```

Result is:

```
original : Wh00t? it's a -- re@lly-weird {file&name} (with + Plus and__1% #of# [$qRots$!]).mov
sanitised: Wh00t-it's-a-re@lly-weird-filename-with-Plus-and__1-of-qRots.mov
```

Looking at WP function, this emulates it quite well.

Comment: Perhaps, you could have just `[\s-]` instead of `[\r\n\t -]`. Also, 1 `perl` argument may also work.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43517547/5113030).

```sh
EscapeFilename()
{
    printf '%s' "$@" | perl -pe 's/[:;,\?\[\]\/\\=<>''"&\$#*()|~`!{}%+]//g; s/[\s-]+/-/g;';
}
```